# Multicolumn overriding table width

Tags: tables, width

I think multicolumn function is overriding my table width. 4th (1.4cm) and 6th (1.8cm) column width is not as configured, it should be 2.3 cm and then table will get connected with page border.

I have tried to remove multicolumn on 4th and 6th column and then table width is 2.3cm but then I dont have vertical lines :(

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}@{}@{}p{2.95cm}@{}|@{}p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}p{2.3cm}@{}@{}p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}p{2.3cm}@{}@{}p{1.5cm}@{}@{}p{0.8cm}@{}}
```

[image]

my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm},
includehead=false,
includefoot=true,footskip=10cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
\fancyhf{}                      %% clear default for head and foot
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+(2.5cm,1cm)$) {
        \begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}@{}@{}p{2.95cm}@{}|@{}p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}p{2.3cm}@{}@{}p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}p{2.3cm}@{}@{}p{1.5cm}@{}@{}p{0.8cm}@{}}
        \cline{3-8}     
        &
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}         
        &
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}         
        &
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}         
        &
        & \centering\textbf{\scriptsize A}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\scriptsize 1}}
        & \centering\textbf{\scriptsize 1}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\scriptsize 1}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{\textbf{\scriptsize 1}}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}         
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize Rev.:}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize Datum:}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize Gezeichnet:}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize Überprüft:}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{\scriptsize Genehmigt:}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \scriptsize Klient:
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\includegraphics[valign=c,scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize Dummy text}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \scriptsize Auftragnehmer:
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\includegraphics[valign=c,scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize Dummy text}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{\scriptsize Projekt:}
        & \scriptsize Vertrag Nr.:
        & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l|}{\scriptsize Dokument Nr.:}
        & \scriptsize Seite:
        & \textbf{\footnotesize \thepage}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{7-8} 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\makecell{\footnotesize 1}}}
        &
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\footnotesize 1}} 
        & \makecell[l]{\scriptsize Gesamte\\\scriptsize Seite:}
        & \textbf{\footnotesize \pageref*{LastPage}}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{\scriptsize Titel:}
        & \scriptsize Rahmen:
        & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l|}{\scriptsize Rev.:}
        & \scriptsize Format:
        & \textbf{\footnotesize A4}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{7-8} 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\footnotesize 1}}
        & \centering\textbf{\footnotesize 1:1}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\footnotesize A}}
        & \scriptsize Sprache:
        & \textbf{\footnotesize DE}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
Dummy text
\end{document}
```

Comment: please limit your document example only to table. if `\multicolum` spilling out of table border, than you need to define it width for example with column type `p{<width>}`, which will in the case of longer text in its content break it in more lines.

Comment: Hi @Zarko, I have reduced MWE, i have defined column width with `p{<width>}` but it is smaller than it should be.

Comment: your example is not very minimal still! also it has dozens of `\multicolumn` and it's not clear which one you are asking about, or how you want the output to change.

Comment: note that the yellow measurements on your image are not taking account of the width of the vertical rules. Perhaps that is the issue? (but I can not tell what you want to change in the output)

Comment: now i'm on the way. i will look your question very late evening again, if meantime some else solve your problem. if not, i will try to do:-)

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle I want that my 4th(1.4cm) and 6th(1.8cm) column be 2.3cm as i specified -->  `\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}@{}@{}p{2.95cm}@{}|@{}p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}p{2.3cm}@{}@{}p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}p{2.3cm}@{}@{}p{1.5cm}@{}@{}p{0.8cm}@{}}`.

Comment: really you should make an example that removes all the page foot and tikz node wrapping and just has a small two or three row tabular that is not working as you expect. I really can not see what you want to change.

Comment: oh I see ... answer coming up...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This table is in my first page footer, and from second to last page I have only header. I want to change 4th and 6th column width so my table connect with page border. I want 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th column width to be 2.3cm as specified, but when i print document 3rd column width is 2.3cm (that is ok), 4th column width is 1.4cm (I want 2.3cm), 5th column width is 2.3cm (that is ok) and 6th column width is 1.8cm (I want 2.3cm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove almost all the `\multicolumn{1}` from the table as they are doing nothing useful:  If you use `\multicolumn` in every cell in a column then the default column specification is not used at all.

Here you specified a `p` column in the table preamble but then you replaced that by `c` in every entry so the column is set to the natural width of its content.

You want that column to be a centred, scriptsize parbox with a vertical rule so specify it as

```
>{\centering \scriptsize}p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}
```

then the cell data needs no extra markup and can simply be

```
        & Datum:
```

I just did that one case here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm},
includehead=false,
includefoot=true,footskip=10cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
\fancyhf{}                      %% clear default for head and foot
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+(2.5cm,1cm)$) {
        \begin{tabular}{
@{}p{3cm}@{}@{}
p{2.95cm}@{}|@{}
p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}
>{\centering \scriptsize}p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}
p{2.3cm}@{}|@{}
p{2.3cm}@{}@{}
p{1.5cm}@{}@{}
p{0.8cm}@{}
}
        \cline{3-8}     
        &
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}         
        &
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}         
        &
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}         
        &
        & \centering\textbf{\scriptsize A}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\scriptsize 1}}
        & \centering\textbf{\scriptsize 1}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\scriptsize 1}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{\textbf{\scriptsize 1}}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}         
        &
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize Rev.:}
        & Datum:
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize Gezeichnet:}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize Überprüft:}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c }{\scriptsize Genehmigt:}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \scriptsize Klient:
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\includegraphics[valign=c,scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize Dummy text}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \scriptsize Auftragnehmer:
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\includegraphics[valign=c,scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize Dummy text}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{\scriptsize Projekt:}
        & \scriptsize Vertrag Nr.:
        & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l|}{\scriptsize Dokument Nr.:}
        & \scriptsize Seite:
        & \textbf{\footnotesize \thepage}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{7-8} 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\makecell{\footnotesize 1}}}
        &
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\footnotesize 1}} 
        & \makecell[l]{\scriptsize Gesamte\\\scriptsize Seite:}
        & \textbf{\footnotesize \pageref*{LastPage}}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{\scriptsize Titel:}
        & \scriptsize Rahmen:
        & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l|}{\scriptsize Rev.:}
        & \scriptsize Format:
        & \textbf{\footnotesize A4}
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{7-8} 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\footnotesize 1}}
        & \centering\textbf{\footnotesize 1:1}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\footnotesize A}}
        & \scriptsize Sprache:
        & \textbf{\footnotesize DE}
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
Dummy text
\end{document}
```